# Django - Application Database Tables not creating

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I seem to be bumping into an issue where the database tables for my applications are not creating successfully in SQL Server Management Studio. I can confirm that I have deleted the database table, created a new database table, deleted the content of the migrations folder of the app I was migrating, I have then executed `python manage.py makemigrations <appname>` and `python manage.py migrate <appname>`.

EDIT: Makemigrations and Migrate both executed without error.

EDIT 2: The database setting is as follows - hostname and password omitted here for security:

[image: The database setting is as follows - hostname and password omitted here for security]

EDIT 3: The table django_migrations is appearing in the relevant database, however this table is empty despite a populated 0001.py migration file which contains the necessary models with table names. The managed setting is set to 'True'.

Still no joy.

All my models use database routing for read and write operations, I have checked to make sure that the routing is set up correctly and can confirm the routing is set up correctly.

The username and passwords for SQL seem to be OK since no errors are thrown.

Overall, it appears the set up is correct and that the only issue is that the tables aren't creating!

Comment: Did you run "makemigrations" and "migrate" without errors? Did you add your new app in INSTALLED_APPS?  How does your DATABASES variable in settings.py look like?

Comment: Hi, yes I have added your comments as edits in my original question. I can confirm that all of your suggestions have been implemented and verified as correct.

Comment: @NeilFaulkner you need to delete Django code tables that holds migrations history, currently i don't remember they name. After this you migrations shell create new tables.

Comment: Did you clear out the python cache in the migration folder? Something the migrations linger there.

Comment: I have deleted the default database used in my Routers, and then re-created the default database with the same credentials. I have used the commands 'makemigration' and 'migrate' and 'sqlmigrate' - all the django commands seem to work fine with no error. However, still no database tables...

Comment: I have tried executing 'sql migrate' - it would appear in command prompt that this commits to create the model. It does not appear to create and commit database tables.